# Setting the http port for gradle/ratpack on the command line

Tags: groovy, gradle, ratpack

I am trying to run ratpack [(https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/tree/master/src/templates/ratpack)](https://github.com/pledbrook/lazybones/tree/master/src/templates/ratpack)

using "gradlew run" - this uses a default port, is there a way to set the port on the command line that will be used for http?

Something like gradlew run -Dhttp.port=8080 or similar?

Answer (score 7):

You need to configure it at the build level…

```
run {
  jvmArgs "-Dratpack.port=8080"
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw that, I should have been clearer: is there a way the number can come from the environment/system properties? rather than hard code it?

Answer (score 1):

Try, when executing the application:

```
RATPACK_SERVER__PORT=5051 ./gradlew run
```